# How to publish event from a page and receive it from another page with rxjs

Tags: angular, events, rxjs

in my project, when I back from page1.ts, I want to trigger an event in page2.ts
something like:
page1.ts

```
  closeFrom(): void {
    //publish an event hear 
    this.event.publish('someEvent', {name: 'a name'})
    history.back();
  }
```

page2.ts

```
this.event.subscribe('someEvent', (data) => {
    const name = data.name;
})
```

Thank you so much :D

Comment: Are these components related somehow? Like parent-child for example

Comment: @SparrowVic it's two different components, no relationship, do you have any solution? thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case there is no relation between those two components - the best practice is to have a `Subject` variable inside the service and both components should inject that service - for example:

```
 export MyService {
    formClosed = new Subject();
}
```

first component:

```
export firstComponent {   
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
    closeFrom(): void {
    this.myService.formClosed.next(true)
    this.event.publish('someEvent', {name: 'a name'})
    history.back();
    }
  }
```

second component

```
 export secondComponent {
     constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
 
     ngOnInit() {
       this.myService.formClosed.subscribe(isClosed => {
             // do something if it return true
        })
  }
```